# What is the correct url for the youtube query API

Tags: url, youtube-api

I am trying to use the youtube query API. From the google developers page, I got this sample:

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=football+-soccer&orderby=published&start-index=11&max-results=10&v=2

But this does not work. What I really want to do is find a list of videos, not more than 10 min in length but with views more than 10,000, launched within the last 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

This is the old depriciated API. Use the new V3 Api https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/?hl=en